# Word to describe a person of planet earth?

Tags: single-word-requests

It is common knowledge that should a creature exist on Mars, for instance, it would be considered 'Martian'; however there is no such term (to my knowledge) to describe us, dwellers of Earth.

Earthen makes the most sense but it doesn't follow conventions, Terran is also a term I have heard floating around.

Is there a recognised term for 'Earth creatures'?

Comment: As I understand it, [Fred Hoyle and Chandra Wickramasinghe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5lFeW1FWfo) think *all* life in the solar system originated in the [Oort cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oort_cloud). ***Oortian***, anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Earthling**, I believe, is the word you are looking for.

> *NOUN:*  an inhabitant of earth

[Ref.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/earthling?s=t)

Additional history on earthling from the same reference:

...science fiction sense of "inhabitant of the planet Earth" first attested 1949 in writing of Robert Heinlein. Earlier in this sense was earthite (1825).

Comment: Although **earthling** would be my answer it has the problem of being constructed with the pejorative/diminutive suffix "-ling".  This is most likely due to its birth from the mouth of a chauvinist science fiction alien.  Please, let's do better than to introduce ourselves to the rest of the universe with a noun that has the same connotation as "weakling".

Comment: I think Terran has a more noble ring to it, but hey, the English language doesn't work based on nobility!

Answer (score 1):

"[Terrestrial](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/terrestrial)" would make sense. Another word used often in science fiction is [earthling](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/earthling?s=t). See also [this list of words](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikisaurus:Earthling) meaning "inhabitant of Earth."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **Earthling** is the best choice recognized by OED. I also found the following words:

1. Earthian: an inhabitant of the earth - recognized by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/earthian) but not OED.
2. Terran: (in science fiction) an inhabitant of the earth - recognized by [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/terran).